# Conditional statement for find and replace in Notepad++ or any text editor

Tags: xml, replace, notepad++

I'm going to keep it simple. I was given this xml file to fix. It has over 10000 profiles on this xml file. Within the profiles there are < Coverage> < /Coverage> tags. I was curious to see if anyone know if Notepad++ supports conditional statements for find and replace or if they are familiar with a text editor being able to do so. The reason behind that is that if the integer between the coverage tag is <150000 then it presents issues for me. So being able to find all the tags, analyze the tags and if by chance the value is smaller than 150000.. replace it with 150000.

*Even a plugin I'm unfamiliar with could be the solution

Here is an example of a profile

```
<FortusTransaction Type="Property">
<Carriers>
<Carrier />
</Carriers>
<Province>NB</Province>
<CodeNames>
<Homeowners>
<QuoteInfo>
<ID>140061761 </ID>
<AssumeMultiLine>Y </AssumeMultiLine>
 <Dwelling>
  <DwellingType>H</DwellingType>
  <CityName>SAINT JOHN </CityName>
  <PostalCode></PostalCode>
  <Prov>NB </Prov>
  <FormType>2 </FormType>
  <Value>140000</Value>
  <Coverage>140000</Coverage>
  <DwellingDate>19660101 </DwellingDate>
  <Liab>-1</Liab>
  <PP>-1</PP>
  <PrmHeatType>CENTRAL FURNACE - GAS </PrmHeatType>
  <PrmHeatApproved>1</PrmHeatApproved>
  <AuxHeat1Type>NONE </AuxHeat1Type>
  <AuxHeat1Approved>1</AuxHeat1Approved>
  <ProtectionClass>P </ProtectionClass>
  <Ded>500 </Ded>
  <DobIns>19860101 </DobIns>
  <NumMortgage>1</NumMortgage>
  <BurgAlarm>NONE </BurgAlarm>
  <Structure>DETACHED </Structure>
  <RoofType>ASPHALT SHINGLES </RoofType>
  <RoofDate>19660101 </RoofDate>
  <Construction>FRAME </Construction>
  <ElectType>COPPER </ElectType>
  <ElectServ>100 AMP </ElectServ>
  <ElectDate>19660101 </ElectDate>
  <PlumbType>COPPER </PlumbType>
  <PlumbDate>19660101 </PlumbDate>
  <OwnerOcc>1</OwnerOcc>
  <OccSince>19660101 </OccSince>
  <InsSince>20060525</InsSince>
  <NumFam>1</NumFam>
  <NumStoreys>1 </NumStoreys>
  <ResidenceCov>
   <Apply>1</Apply>
   <Amount>140000 </Amount>
  </ResidenceCov>
  <SewerBackupExt>
   <Apply>1</Apply>
   <Coverage>140000 </Coverage>
  </SewerBackupExt>
   <Claim>
    <ClaimDate>19900415 </ClaimDate>
    <ClaimType>OTHER </ClaimType>
    <Amount>600 </Amount>
    <Forgiven>0 </Forgiven>
   </Claim>
 </Dwelling>
 </QuoteInfo>
 </Homeowners>
 </CodeNames>
 </FortusTransaction>
```

I would like to add that there is also a possibility of having a space between the tag. So to simply replace everything between the tags would be necessary. For example
of another profile

```
<Value>142000 </Value>
  <Coverage>142000 </Coverage>
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Can you show some example tags? (Paste them to your question.)

Comment: Can the number be negative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that using Regular Expressions.

Use the regex below at the ***Find what:*** field:

```
<Coverage>\s*(1[0-4]|[0-9])?[0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]\s*</Coverage>
```

And ***Replace with:***

```
<Coverage>150000</Coverage>
```

This will replace every `<Coverage>number</Coverage>` string where the `number` is smaller than `150000`.

Check **[this online demo](http://regexr.com?35o1f)**. The blue text is what will be matched and replaced. Do some tests, write some examples and make sure it matches what you expect.

#### Usage on Notepad++:

Make sure you check the ***Regular Expression*** radio in the ***Search mode*** box. Check an example below.

[image: example notepadpp]